# install windows 7 and ubuntu on the same partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows, windows-7

i was wondering if i could install windows 7 and Ubuntu on the same hard drive partition.. when i select "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows " it creates another partition to install Ubuntu int... but what i want is to install Ubuntu in the same partition as that of windows..

after searching he whole internet i'm starting to think that it's not possible as there will be a confliction between windows and Ubuntu boot-loader... but i'm not sure about that..

there is this post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347437/installation-of-ubuntu-13-04-and-windows-7-on-same-partition) but it doesn't fit to my situation.. thanks!

Comment: In short: no it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A boot entry is registered in the [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) for a partition. A partition can only have one purpose, it is either a operating system or something else.
It cannot be two operating systems at the same time.

Imagine if you had two operating systems on one partition, which one should the MBR call? The first or the last?
So in short, you actually start a partition (via the MBR) which then loads the OS.

Comment: In (u)EFI, the same thing happens. However, MBR isn't used.